# Apache redirect 301 remove trailing slash from certain URLs only

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to figure out how to remove trailing slashes from only certain URLs using Apache rewrites / redirects.

For example:

I want to 301 redirect www.example.com/woo/ to www.example.com/woo

I only want to remove the trailing slash from certain URLs.

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? `RedirectMatch ^/woo/$ http://www.example.com/woo` should work. UNLESS woo is a directory, because Apache recognizes that and redirects to woo/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single URL:

```
RedirectMatch ^/woo/$ http://www.example.com/woo
```

Use a regex group alternation for multiple URLs:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(woo|cage|travolta)/$ http://www.example.com/$1
```

Will work for these three examples:

```
http://www.example.com/woo/
http://www.example.com/cage/
http://www.example.com/travolta/
```